# have a friendship or have friendship

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

> BBC: I have **friendship** with all the living beings
>
> The New York Times: I have multiple doormen and I have **a friendship** with one of them

**According to Cambridge, friendship is both countable and uncountable noun but I am not sure when to use either version?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be countable or uncountable. When *uncountable*, you would not use the possessive "have", as in your example. This is because, while the countable refers to one of the potentially many relationships you may have, the uncountable refers to a *state* or the *concept* of friendship.

"Countable" Examples:

- I have *a* friendship with John.
- I have *many friendships*.

Uncountable examples:

- Friendship with John can be difficult.
- John is looking for friendship.